# Issue while trying to setup the spring-boot open source project from Github

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, setup-project, gradle-wrapper

I was trying to setup the [spring boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) open source project in order to contribute it. I was going through the steps in [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Working-with-the-Code). I am on the `main` branch. When I try to run

```
./gradlew build
```

I am getting this error

```
* Where:
Settings file '<my local path>/spring-boot/settings.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'io.spring.ge.conventions', version: '0.0.12'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.spring.ge.conventions:io.spring.ge.conventions.gradle.plugin:0.0.12')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    maven(https://repo.spring.io/release)
    maven2(https://repo.spring.io/snapshot)
```

settings.gradle contains this at [line 26](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/3bcc7ece55f88f3de6e59253205bfb5342d45a67/settings.gradle#L26)

```
    id "io.spring.ge.conventions" version "0.0.12"
```

From what I understand in the above log, gradle is trying to search for `io.spring.ge.conventions` but its not able to find it in those repositories. I haven't used gradle before so I am not sure what the issue is exactly and how to fix it.

These are my system details:

```
System: Mac(Intel)
java version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
Editor: Intellij
```

I don't have gradle installed separately. I am using the gradle wrapper provided by the project.

Additionally I just commented out that line in `settings.gradle` and ran the build. It succeeded.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: I'm also confused, because [although that plugin was recently updated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/68531bfba96146c32ffe41a18358c211418b06d8), the [new version exists in repo.spring.io/release](https://repo.spring.io/ui/native/release/io/spring/ge/conventions/gradle-enterprise-conventions-gradle-plugin/). I recommend you create an issue on the Spring Boot GitHub project.

Comment: Ok. I am able to build the project successfully now. Maybe when I was trying to setup the project a few days back, the jars were not present (?) in those upstream servers. Let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks for replying and taking the time to help out.